# How to use OSGI with CDI in jboss?

Tags: osgi, cdi, jboss-weld, jboss-eap-6

I'm experimenting with OSGI and CDI. I want to register my OSGI services using CDI annotations and also retrieve the registered OSGI services using CDI.

I have found the following: https://github.com/mathieuancelin/weld-osgi, it seems like it is integrated into weld-core. But when I depenend on the weld-core 1.2.0.Beta1 or 2.0.0.Final version, I do not find any of the annotations specified in the documentation on https://github.com/mathieuancelin/weld-osgi.

It this weld-osgi the way to go when you want to use OSGI with CDI? Or should I use spring? (I prefer weld because my AS is currently jboss EAP 6.1)

In which dependency can I find the annotations specified in the documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Currently I do not advice using CDI to work with OSGi services. The Weld-OSGi library is still very experimental and will most likely change when the OSGi-CDI specification is released.

At this moment a new specification, OSGi-CDI (RFC 193) is being written in the Enterprise OSGi expert group (I'm one of the members writing this spec). OSGi-CDI is scheduled to be part of Enterprise OSGi R6 early next year. Unfortunately, it's too early to start using this yet, the reference implementation is far from finished. Some more details about the upcoming specification can be found in a presentation I gave at EclipseCon this year: https://speakerdeck.com/paulbakker/rfc-193-osgi-cdi

I strongly advice to use one of the other dependency injection solutions available for OSGi services, preferably either Apache Felix Dependency Manager or Dynamic Services. Because both of these libraries are built directly on the OSGi service API, you don't have to drag in other dependencies. The programming model is obviously different than CDI, but the concepts are very similar, so it should be easy to pick up.

Do not use Spring either because it doesn't really fit OSGi very well (although it can work).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on it, and I know little about weld-osgi, but you should be using it if you want OSGi and CDI to play nicely. I'm pretty sure they're separate jars, you'll need to add the weld-osgi dependency to your project.